# Optimize/Vectorize Database Query with R

Tags: r, database, function, loops, dbi

I am attempting to use R to query a large database. Due to the size of the database, I have written the query to fetch 100 rows at a time My code looks something like:

```
library(RJDBC)
library(DBI)
library(tidyverse)

options(java.parameters = "-Xmx8000m")

drv<-JDBC("driver name", "driver path.jar")

conn<-
  dbConnect(
    drv, 
    "database info",
    "username",
    "password"
)

query<-"SELECT * FROM some_table"

hc<-tibble()
res<-dbSendQuery(conn,query)
repeat{
  chunk<-dbFetch(res,100)
  if(nrow(chunk)==0){break}
  hc<-bind_rows(hc,chunk)
  print(nrow(hc))
}
```

Basically, I would like write something that does the same thing, but via the combination of `function` and `lapply`. In theory, given the way R processes data via loops, using `lapply` will speed up query. Some understanding of the `dbFetch` function may help. Specifically, how in the `repeat` loop it doesn't just keep selecting the first initial 100 rows.

I have tried the following, but nothing works:

```
df_list <- lapply(query , function(x) dbGetQuery(conn, x)) 

hc<-tibble()
res<-dbSendQuery(conn,query)
test_query<-function(x){
  chunk<-dbFetch(res,100)
  if(nrow(chunk)==0){break}
  print(nrow(hc))
}
bind_rows(lapply(test_query,res))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works well, as it allows the user to customize the size and number of chunks. Ideally, the function would be Vectorized somehow.

I explored getting the number of rows to automatically set the chunk number, but I couldn't find any methods without actually needing to perform the query first. Adding a large number of chunks doesn't add a ton of extra process time. The performance improvement over the `repeat` approach depends on the size of the data, but the bigger the data the bigger the performance improvement.

Chunks of n = 1000 seem to consistently produce the best results. Any suggestions to these points would be much appreciated.

Solution:

```
library(RJDBC)
library(DBI)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

res<-dbSendQuery(conn,"SELECT * FROM some_table")
##Multiplied together need to be greater than N
chunk_size<-1000
chunk_number<-150

run_chunks<-
  function(chunk_number, res, chunk_size) {

    chunk <- 
     tryCatch(
      dbFetch(res, chunk_size),   
      error = function(e) NULL
     )

   if(!is.null(chunk)){
      return(chunk)
      }
    }


dat<-
  bind_rows(
    lapply(
      1:chunk_number,
      run_chunks,
      res,
      chunk_size
      )
    )
```

Comment: I'm playing with this now but I am eager to think about ways to parallelize and accelerate this! A query that runs in a few minutes directly in MS SQL Server directly on the server that hosts the DB takes over an hour to return the full d.f. in R, and I want to find a better workflow!

Comment: @michael that’s the whole point of the question lol. Feel free to post if you find a better solution!

Answer (score 4):

Consider following the example in [dbFetch docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/DBI/versions/0.5-1/topics/dbFetch) that checks for completed status of fetch, `dbHasCompleted`. Then, for memory efficiency build a list of data frames/tibbles with `lapply` then row bind **once** outside the loop.

```
rs <- dbSendQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM some_table")

run_chunks <- function(i, res) {
  # base::transform OR dplyr::mutate
  # base::tryCatch => for empty chunks depending on chunk number
  chunk <- tryCatch(transform(dbFetch(res, 100), chunk_no = i),    
                    error = function(e) NULL)
  return(chunk)
}

while (!dbHasCompleted(rs)) {
  # PROVIDE SUFFICIENT NUMBER OF CHUNKS (table rows / fetch rows)
  df_list <- lapply(1:5, run_chunks, res=rs)                      
}

# base::do.call(rbind, ...) OR dplyr::bind_rows(...) 
final_df <- do.call(rbind, df_list)
```

---

Demonstration with in-memory SQLite database of `mtcars`:

```
con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")

dbWriteTable(con, "mtcars", mtcars)

run_chunks <- function(i, res) {
  chunk <- dbFetch(res, 10)
  return(chunk)
}

rs <- dbSendQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM mtcars")

while (!dbHasCompleted(rs)) {
  # PROVIDE SUFFICIENT NUMBER OF CHUNKS (table rows / fetch rows)

  df_list <- lapply(1:5, function(i) 
    print(run_chunks(i, res=rs))
  )
}

do.call(rbind, df_list)

dbClearResult(rs)
dbDisconnect(con)
```

**Output** *(5 chunks of 10 rows, 10 rows, 10 rows, 2 rows, 0 rows, and full 32 rows)*

```
#     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# 1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# 2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# 3  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
# 4  21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
# 5  18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
# 6  18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
# 7  14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
# 8  24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
# 9  22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
# 10 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4

#     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# 1  17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
# 2  16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
# 3  17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
# 4  15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
# 5  10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
# 6  10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
# 7  14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
# 8  32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
# 9  30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
# 10 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1

#     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# 1  21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
# 2  15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
# 3  15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
# 4  13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
# 5  19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
# 6  27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
# 7  26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
# 8  30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
# 9  15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
# 10 19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6

#    mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt qsec vs am gear carb
# 1 15.0   8  301 335 3.54 3.57 14.6  0  1    5    8
# 2 21.4   4  121 109 4.11 2.78 18.6  1  1    4    2

# [1] mpg  cyl  disp hp   drat wt   qsec vs   am   gear carb
# <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

do.call(rbind, df_list)
#     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# 1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# 2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# 3  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
# 4  21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
# 5  18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
# 6  18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
# 7  14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
# 8  24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
# 9  22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
# 10 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
# 11 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
# 12 16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
# 13 17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
# 14 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
# 15 10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
# 16 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
# 17 14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
# 18 32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
# 19 30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
# 20 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
# 21 21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
# 22 15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
# 23 15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
# 24 13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
# 25 19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
# 26 27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
# 27 26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
# 28 30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
# 29 15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
# 30 19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
# 31 15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
# 32 21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
```

Comment: the `while` loop doesn't work quite right as `dbHasCompleted` appears to be TRUE as soon as the connection is established (not when the query is complete). Also, the data sets I deal with range in size quite a bit, so I wanted to give more flexibility as I queried. Moreover, there is no reason to add `chunk_no` as a column, as it adds process time. `tryCatch` was  a good idea though. I was able to build an effective solution using it (see below).

Comment: Very interesting as I tested this code before posting! See extension demo, printing out every chunk and final data frame.